# Adding Google Search API to Android App

Tags: android, google-search-api

Hi i would like to add google search api to my application.and the search result should be shown in a list view...can any one send me some example or tell me how to do it??

Comment: Check this link it will help you. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here it is:

```
import android.app.SearchManager;

// ...

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);  
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "Search query");    
startActivity(intent);
```

Voice-based search:

```
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;

// ...

Intent sp = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
sp.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
sp.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak please");
startActivity(sp);
```

Comment: can u please sent ur total code

Comment: I remember that it's possible to provide search results for the Google-Search app, and that this was announced a very long time ago. Do you know perhaps where to find such a thing in the docs?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good example on implementing google search in your android application [Implementing google search](http://dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-how-implement-google)
.Hope it helps.

Comment: The link is dead.