# Android studio, get image from google

Tags: android, image, android-studio

I can't find any up-to date information, so I'm asking here. How can I google search a link like this: "https://www.google.com/search?q=Pony". An receive back an url to the first Pony Image, that google finds?

Comment: Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492869/adding-google-search-api-to-android-app)?

Comment: @SqueezyMo I need to get the image url with no user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  Google Custom Search API for your task.
Check out this [link](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview).

Comment: Is there a simpler way of doing so? This API doesn't have a lot of documentation for Android.

Comment: Checkout this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/what-are-the-alternatives-now-that-the-google-web-search-api-has-been-deprecated